# Back button skipping pages

Tags: php, browser, server, settings, windows-server

When I click the back button OR backspace on a webpage, only on my website, the page skips 2/3 pages.

For example, if I visit the following:
www.domain.co.uk/page1.php
www.domain.co.uk/page2.php
www.domain.co.uk/page3.php
www.domain.co.uk/page4.php

If I click "Back" or hit the return key on page4.php, I am returned to page1.php instead of page3.php.

I have noticed this across browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE and Edge) but only on my website. Other websites are fine. It is also across multiple computers, immediately pointing at the site configuration.

I have no idea where to start to look. I've googled the issue, which just returns browser specific issues, usually when multiple plug ins are installed and conflicting, but I can rule this out, as multiple machines are affected, including machines with no plug ins installed at all.

The website uses PHP files, and is hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2 - Not sure if this is helpful..

If any more information is required, let me know and I will happily provide them.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, tested by avoiding pages with redirects and worked as it should. Why would redirects cause this issue?

Comment: Are you using redirections on the pages which are skipped?

Comment: Some pages do, others do not. I can test it purely on pages that i know do not have any redirects if that will help?

Comment: I think the redirects might be causing this.. Just tested on pages without and it goes back to the previous page successfully. Now, why would my redirects cause this?

Comment: Because redirects can mean that the page is some kind of a temporary for the user.

Comment: How are your redirects done? Via HTML?

Comment: Combination of HTML, JS and PHP redirects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question got more clear:

Your redirects are causing the browser to skip the pages which cause redirects to other pages when pressing the back button. Take look at this [article](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback).

Comment: Thank you. Been an annoying issue for far too long has this! Appreciate the help!